# Determine the intersection between surfaces of two 3D-meshes one inside the other

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, vtk, surface

I have two meshes that are centered in the origin of the axes, one inside the other. I have implemented an easy function in vtk to scale the internal mesh. The idea is to stop this cycle when the surface of the internal mesh comes into contact with the surface of the external one. I tried to use vtk libraries but I haven't found nothing. The vtk boolean intersection work well but seems to be useless.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?
Is there a function in vtk that could do this?

Comment: As far as I know does VTK not come with collision detection features. You would have to construct your own tool. Some VTK users discussed your question in [this nabble thread](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/collision-detection-with-vtk-td5722845.html).

Comment: There is [vtkbioeng](http://www.bioengineering-research.com/software/vtkbioeng) that implemented a collision detection filter. I never used it, so I can't tell how good it works. The project looks a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for an intersection with `vtkInterface`:

```
import numpy as np
import vtkInterface as vtki

# create a test sphere
sphere = vtki.Sphere(radius=1.0)

# generate a cylinder inside the sphere and change its height
# and test for an intersection
for height in np.linspace(1, 3, 50):
    cylinder = vtki.Cylinder([0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0],
                             0.2, height).TriFilter()

    # test intersection
    cut_mesh = cylinder.BooleanCut(sphere)

    # cut_mesh will be empty when there's no intersection
    if cut_mesh.GetNumberOfPoints():
        break


plotter = vtki.PlotClass()
plotter.AddMesh(sphere, style='wireframe')
plotter.AddMesh(cylinder, 'b', opacity=0.2, showedges=False)
plotter.AddMesh(cut_mesh, 'r', showedges=False)
plotter.Plot()
```

This intersects when the cylinder has a height of 2.11 and generates the following plot:

[image: Intersection Screenshot]

I saw that you had trouble installing vtkInterface for Mac OS.  I've since updated the source and uploaded 0.11.3 to PyPi.  Please reinstall with:

```
pip install vtkInterface --upgrade
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your idea. At the end I solve the problem using the distances; the code works with vtk.vtkCellLocator, computing the points of each cell, searching for the coordinates of the three vertex and calculating the ideal center point of each cell. Than, using FindClosestPoint function, I select the lower distance in order to move closer the inside mesh to the surface of the outside mesh.